# How do I put a div under the other?

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble positioning the "socials" div under neath the "nav" div. what am I missing?
here is my html

```css
#nav{
background-color: #fcb254;
height: auto;
width: 20%;
background-color: #fcb254;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
border-radius: ;
border: solid 3px #f19828;
float: left;
}
#nav ul{
padding: 5px;
}
#nav ul li{
display: block;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
font-size: 23px;
}
#nav ul li a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover{
background-color: #3c79a1;
}

#socials {
background-color: #fcb254;
height: auto;
width: 20%;
background-color: #fcb254;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
border-radius: ;
border: solid 3px #f19828;
float: left;
clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="socials">
    <center>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    </center>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <center>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up/Log In</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </center>
</div>
```

Sorry about the code spam but im pretty new to this coding business so I am trying my best

edit: the "clear: left;" tag works but the body is positioned way too far low if you know what I mean.

Comment: Why don't you place the `.socials` div after the `.nav` div in your code ?

Comment: it is like that in the code but thats just how i pasted it here...

Comment: What do you mean by underneath? Below like placement or behind like stacking order?

Comment: You might want to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). I'm making an answer...

Comment: If its like that in the code. It's probably best to put it like that here

Comment: just a few notes: you have `background-color` twice within the stylings. You have a rule without a value (`border-radius: ;`).

Comment: Note that the center tag is obsolete, it no longer exists.

Comment: My first thought was to switch the divs around as well. The code you provide here should be an accurate copy of the code that you are asking about.

Comment: Read about positioning here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: not answering your Q' but if you are building webapps and dont want to get to deep into CSS maybe you should look at a front-end component library such as bootstrap. It does a lot of the layout for you which may suite you more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `float: left;` from the nav element and add `display: block;` to both `#nav` and `#socials`.

By definition `Block` level elements do not sit inline but break past them. By default (without setting a width) they take up as much horizontal space as they can.

HTML:

```
<div id="socials">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <center>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up/Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </center>
</div>
```

CSS applied:

```
#nav{
    background-color: #fcb254;
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: solid 3px #f19828;
    display: block;
}
#socials {
    background-color: #fcb254;
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #fcb254;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: ;
    border: solid 3px #f19828;
    display: block;
}
```

My result:

[image]

Find more about the display property [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container { /* Added this container and the item class */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    width: 20%;
}

.item {
    background-color: #fcb254;
    border: solid 3px #f19828;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.center {
    text-align: center !important; /* mimics the <center> tag */
}

/*
#nav{
    background-color: #fcb254;
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: ;
    border: solid 3px #f19828;
    float: left;
}
*/

#nav ul{
    padding: 5px;
}

#nav ul li{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-size: 23px;
}

#nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #3c79a1;
}

/*
#socials {
    background-color: #fcb254;
    height: auto;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: ; Commented due to lack of value 
    border: solid 3px #f19828;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" id="socials">
        <center>
            <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook"></a>
        </center>
    </div>
    <div class="item" id="nav">
        <ul class="center">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up/Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```